# Neo4j OGM fails to clear null-ed relationship on save

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

- Neo4j Community 4.0.3
- Windows 10
- bolt driver accessed via Java 11 OGM framework
- Steps to reproduce...

I've created the two (`Car` and `Person`) classes below, then run the third (`PocTest`) class as a JUnit test.  I'd expected the final assertNull to pass, but it fails: the relationship that had been set, saved, then cleared and saved again, did not appear to have its clearing/null-ing persisted by the final save.

This seems odd to me, so I'm wondering if it's a bug... but accept it is most likely a lack of knowledge on my part.

(I'm wondering if I need to create an explicit relationship class, then use its identifier to delete it, but given I may not want any other attributes on that, I'd prefer not to if I don't need to.)

Any understanding anyone could provide to me on this would be most welcome. Thank you!

```
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GeneratedValue;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Id;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship;

@NodeEntity( label = "Car" )
public class Car {

  @GeneratedValue
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @Relationship( type = "DRIVER", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING )
  private Person driver;

  public Long getId()
  {
    return this.id;
  }

  public Person getDriver()
  {
    return this.driver;
  }

  public void setDriver( final Person driver )
  {
    this.driver = driver;
  }
}
```

```
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Id;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;

@NodeEntity( label = "Person" )
public class Person {

  @Id
  private String name;

  public String getName()
  {
    return this.name;
  }

  public void setName( final String name )
  {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNull;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

public class PoCTest {

  private static SessionFactory ogmSessionFactory;

  @BeforeAll
  private static void createSessionFactory()
  {
    final Configuration config = new Configuration.Builder().uri( "bolt://localhost:7687" )
          .credentials( "neo4j", "blahblahblah..." )
          .useNativeTypes()
          .verifyConnection( true )
          .build();
    ogmSessionFactory = new SessionFactory( config, PoCTest.class.getPackageName() );
  }

  private static Session getOgmSession()
  {
    return ogmSessionFactory.openSession();
  }

  @Test
  void testCreateCarChangeDriver()
  {
    final Car car = new Car();
    final Person fred = new Person();
    fred.setName( "fred" );
    car.setDriver( fred );       // sets the relationship as expected
    getOgmSession().save( car ); // saves the relationship as expected
    assertEquals( "fred", getOgmSession().load( Car.class, car.getId() ).getDriver().getName() ); // passes
    car.setDriver( null );       // then we clear the relationship ("fred" is no longer the driver)
    getOgmSession().save( car ); // then *save* it... _but_...
    // Bug! The save ^ has *not* cleared the relationship...
    assertNull( getOgmSession().load( Car.class, car.getId() ).getDriver() ); // <- and this line fails!
  }
}
```

Comment: So, a "workaround" is to create a RelationshipEntity class, to represent the `CarDriver`, with the `Car` and `Person` classes referencing that instead of each other (e.g. with access methods that chain to its `Car` and `Driver` members, setting their attributes too but avoiding circular loops etc.), then to _delete_ that actual relationship itself: `getOgmSession().delete(carDriver);`   (This does seem quite involved, compared with what I'd hoped would work above, though.)

Answer (score 0):

The workaround "solution" in full, from my comment above:

```
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GeneratedValue;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Id;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@NodeEntity( label = "Car" )
public class Car {

  @GeneratedValue
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @JsonIgnoreProperties( { "car" } )
  @Relationship( type = "DRIVEN_BY", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING )
  private CarDriver drivenBy;

  public Long getId()
  {
    return this.id;
  }

  public CarDriver getDrivenBy()
  {
    return this.drivenBy;
  }

  public void setDrivenBy( final CarDriver value )
  {
    if( this.drivenBy != null && this.drivenBy.getCar() != this )
    {
      this.drivenBy.setCar( null );
    }
    this.drivenBy = value;
    if( this.drivenBy != null && this.drivenBy.getCar() != this )
    {
      this.drivenBy.setCar( this );
    }
  }
}
```

```
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Id;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@NodeEntity( label = "Person" )
public class Person {

  @Id
  private String name;

  @JsonIgnoreProperties( { "drivenBy" } )
  @Relationship( type = "DRIVEN_BY", direction = Relationship.INCOMING )
  private CarDriver drives;

  public String getName()
  {
    return this.name;
  }

  public void setName( final String name )
  {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public CarDriver getDrives()
  {
    return this.drives;
  }

  public void setDrives( final CarDriver value )
  {
    if( this.drives != null && this.drives.getDriver() != this )
    {
      this.drives.setDriver( null );
    }
    this.drives = value;
    if( this.drives != null && this.drives.getDriver() != this )
    {
      this.drives.setDriver( this );
    }
  }
}
```

```
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.EndNode;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GeneratedValue;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Id;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.RelationshipEntity;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.StartNode;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@RelationshipEntity( type = "DRIVEN_BY" )
public class CarDriver {
  @GeneratedValue
  @Id
  private Long id;
  @JsonIgnoreProperties( "drivenBy" )
  @StartNode
  private Car car;
  @JsonIgnoreProperties( "drives" )
  @EndNode
  private Person driver;

  public Long getId()
  {
    return this.id;
  }

  public Car getCar()
  {
    return this.car;
  }

  public void setCar( final Car car )
  {
    if( this.car != null && this.car.getDrivenBy() != this )
    {
      this.car.setDrivenBy( null );
    }
    this.car = car;
    if( this.car != null && car.getDrivenBy() != this )
    {
      car.setDrivenBy( this );
    }
  }

  public Person getDriver()
  {
    return this.driver;
  }

  public void setDriver( final Person driver )
  {
    if( this.driver != null && this.driver.getDrives() != this )
    {
      this.driver.setDrives( null );
    }
    this.driver = driver;
    if( this.driver != null && driver.getDrives() != this )
    {
      driver.setDrives( this );
    }
  }
}
```

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNull;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

public class PoCTest {

  private static SessionFactory ogmSessionFactory;

  @BeforeAll
  private static void createSessionFactory()
  {
    final Configuration config = new Configuration.Builder().uri( "bolt://localhost:7687" )
          .credentials( "neo4j", StringUtils.replace( "111", "1", "n304j" ) )
          .useNativeTypes()
          .verifyConnection( true )
          .build();
    ogmSessionFactory = new SessionFactory( config, PoCTest.class.getPackageName() );
  }

  private static Session getOgmSession()
  {
    return ogmSessionFactory.openSession();
  }

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp()
  {
    getOgmSession().deleteAll( CarDriver.class );
    getOgmSession().deleteAll( Car.class );
    getOgmSession().deleteAll( Person.class );
  }

  @Test
  void testCreateCarChangeDriver()
  {
    final Car car = new Car();
    final Person fred = new Person();
    fred.setName( "fred" );
    final CarDriver carDriver = new CarDriver();
    carDriver.setCar( car );
    carDriver.setDriver( fred );
    getOgmSession().save( car );
    getOgmSession().delete( carDriver );
    assertNull( getOgmSession().load( Car.class, car.getId() ).getDrivenBy() );
    assertNull( getOgmSession().load( Person.class, fred.getName() ).getDrives() );
  }
}
```